# A difficult limit

Tags: limits

How can I find the limit below?

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}{\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}}$$

Comment: Usually, "trying" is a good first step. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}=\frac{n}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}$$
so the limit is $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that
$${\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}}={\frac{n}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}},$$
and [$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History).